# How do I locate certain words on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, highlighting

I am doing a small project that requires me to locate a certain word and highlight that word inside a web browser.

To put it simply, I have the following questions:

1. I was wondering if there is a location(x,y) tagged to each word on a webpage.
2. Could anybody point me into the direction of some useful tutorials about working within a webpage.

I would like to implement the following code and have it interact with any webpage on google chrome. It is a simple find and highlight function.

```
function doSearch(text) {
if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
    document.designMode = "on";
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

    while (window.find(text)) {
        document.getElementById("button").blur();
        document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "lavender");
        sel.collapseToEnd();
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
} else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    while (textRange.findText(text)) {
        textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "lavender");
        textRange.collapse(false);
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers what you want. Also caters to considering the search term as a phrase or individual words.

[Pure Javascript Search and Text Highlighting](http://www.sks.com.np/article/14/pure-javascript-search-and-text-highlighting.html)

Comment: The actual JavaScript involved looks awful. That's just the wrong way to do this